# Problems with IAP - no products in response.products array

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit

I have problem with In-App Purchase. After sending request to the server there are no products returned by `SKProductsRequest`.

I send the request like this way:

```
    NSMutableSet *identificators = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [identificators addObject:kInAppPurchaseOneWeekIdentifier];
    [identificators addObject:kInAppPurchaseOneMonthIdentifier];
    [identificators addObject:kInAppPurchaseSixMonthsIdentifier];

    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:identificators];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];

    [identificators release];
```

In Consts.h I have those

```
// In App Purchase
#define kInAppPurchaseOneWeekIdentifier              @"com.astroboxapp.iap.OneWeek"
#define kInAppPurchaseOneMonthIdentifier             @"com.astroboxapp.iap.OneMonth"
#define kInAppPurchaseSixMonthsIdentifier            @"com.astroboxapp.iap.SixMonths"
```

In my class I've implemented

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    if ( [response.products count] > 0 ) {
     // i've do my stuff - show the IAP to the user
    } else {
     // here goes the error handling
    }

}
```

In my case `[response.products count]` is empty array/dictionary so i 
throw an error.

EDIT: What i have done ?

1. I created a new IAP's and associate them with my app, I've changed the Products IDs too and change them in my Consts.h
2. I've tried to change the app version from 1.0 to 1.1 somehow that help me to change the IAP for this version.
3. Still not working on my device, while in the simulator there are entries for my IAP but i can test - because of StoreKit don't allow to test purchase from the sumulator.
4. On my device I'am sign out from the store.

Comment: -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response returns you the response of apple server are you sure that your product identifiers are same with the ones that you have in tunes connect.

Comment: The thing is, you define certain products in iTunes connect that your customers can download and you also need to store the identifiers of therese products local in your app.When you request available in app purchases the identifiers that you have locally are sent to apple and compared with the ones that you have defined in iTunes connect.

Comment: you can refer to this detailed tutorial http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Answer (score 2):

if [response invalidProductIdentifers] array is not empty it means your products are not available t download so this is normal that the count of products is empty.just check what you have in response

Comment: When i test it on device it says that all 3 IAP are invalid. They are on "Waiting for Review" status and they are associated with the current app version. App status is "Waiting For Upload"

Comment: Okay i've read official apple documentation for this case, i've found several other resources in SO and everything seem to be okay. But i'am not sure if my last changes before 1-2 hours ago are taking effect.